# php5 - Debugging with gdb CRC mismatch

Tags: php, gdb, php-extension

I'm trying to learn debugging php using gdb. After attaching to a php process I'm recieving errors about debugging symbols for php5-mysql, php5-pgsql. Where can be issue?

```
# gdb -p 33087
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Attaching to process 33087
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/php5...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/php5...done.
done.
...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php5/20100525/curl.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20100525/curl.so...done.
done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php5/20100525/mcrypt.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mcrypt.so...done.
done.
...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysql.so...
warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysql.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysql.so" (CRC mismatch).


warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysql.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysql.so" (CRC mismatch).

(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysql.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysqli.so...
warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysqli.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysqli.so" (CRC mismatch).


warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysqli.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysqli.so" (CRC mismatch).

(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysqli.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_mysql.so...
warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_mysql.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_mysql.so" (CRC mismatch).


warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_mysql.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_mysql.so" (CRC mismatch).

(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_mysql.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_pgsql.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_pgsql.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php5/20100525/pdo_pgsql.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5
...
0x00007fe63e36b18d in poll () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

How to fix errors like "warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysql.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysql.so" (CRC mismatch)."? It is interesting that symbols for other php extension are ok, but only for mysql, mysqli, postgres are failing.

Debian Wheezy `7.6`, all php packages are `5.4.41-0+deb7u1`.

Answer (score 2):

> How to fix errors like `warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysql.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysql.so" (CRC mismatch).`

The warning tells you that the packages from which the two `.so` libraries came are at different versions, and you should update the `-dbg` package to match installed `mysql` package.

This command:

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysql.so \
  /usr/lib/php5/20100525/mysql.so
```

will tell you which packages the `.so`s came from. This command:

```
dpkg -l <package1> <package2>
```

will tell you their installed versions.

Comment: Your solution helps a lot to find out the concerned packages and versions, but if the last command tells you that BOTH packages are at the exact same version, then what would be the issue ?
Had the same exact problem, both concerned packages are 5.4.45-0+deb7ull
Could it means that the files are kinda "corrupted" ?

Comment: @Sorcy Either the files are corrupted (force re-installing may help), or the package builder screwed up (report this as a bug against the repository you got packages from).